# How to set x lim to 99.5 percentile of my data series for matplotlib histogram?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram, outliers

I'm currently pumping out some histograms with matplotlib.  The issue is that because of one or two outliers my whole graph is incredibly small and almost impossible to read due to having two separate histograms being plotted. The solution I am having problems with is dropping the outliers at around a *99/99.5 percentile*.  I have tried using:

```
plt.xlim([np.percentile(df,0), np.percentile(df,99.5)]) 
plt.xlim([df.min(),np.percentile(df,99.5)])
```

Seems like it should be a simple fix, but I'm missing some key information to make it happen. Any input would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to just set the visual limits of the plot, or do you want to actually exclude the outliers before even computing the histogram?

Comment: Just set the visual limits. However, it needs to still be dynamic for multiple graphs.

Comment: Where the outliers fall relative to the 99th percentile will depend on the overall distribution of the data.  Also, it may not be possible to exclude just the outliers depending on how the histogram bins divide the data.  You'll need to show more code with sample data illustrating your situation.  I think in many cases it makes more sense to just exclude the outliers from the histogram computation at an earlier stage.

Comment: So I don't have enough rep to post pictures, but basically it zooms out on the graph to show every data point. Well for my purposes knowing that I have one data point way out of line isn't as necessary as analyzing the heart of the graph.  I'm wondering if it may be easier to exclude them at an earlier stage as you mentioned, what would be the easiest steps down that route?

Comment: Instead of posting a picture, can you post sample code and data showing how you actually create the histogram?

Comment: Check out the sample code just added and let me know if that will suffice. @BrenBarn

Comment: Your sample code doesn't include any histogram nor any sample data.

Answer (score 2):

To restrict focus to just the middle 99% of the values, you could do something like this:

```
trimmed_data = df[(df.Column > df.Column.quantile(0.005)) & (df.Column < df.Column.quantile(0.995))]
```

Then you could do your histogram on `trimmed_data`.  Exactly how to exclude outliers is more of a stats question than a Python question, but basically the idea I was suggesting in a comment is to clean up the data set using whatever methods you can defend, and then do *everything* (plots, stats, etc.) on only the cleaned dataset, rather than trying to tweak each individual plot to make it look right while still having the outlier data in there.

Comment: Not sure what 'd' is set to? And would this need to ran with a series or can it be implemented on an entire df as well? @BrenBarn

Comment: @tylerswright: Sorry, those `d`s were supposed to be `df`.  You can only calculate percentiles on a Series, but you can use those percentiles to subset either a series or a DataFrame.  In my example I subset the DataFrame based on the percentiles of the values in one column (called "Column" here).

Comment: except the missing dot in `df.Columnquantile(0.005)` works perfectly